# Instanciate new object under object

Tags: java, dictionary

Why i can't make this instruction ? and what i can do to make it please ?

> `new HashMap<Integer, new java.util.ArrayList<Long>()>();`

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You probably mean something like:

```
Map<Integer, List<Long>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<Long>>();
List<Long> list = new ArrayList<Long>();
map.put(5, list);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a new instance inside the map. You just want to create a specification of the type.

```
new HashMap<Integer, List<Long>>();
```

Each entry in the map can then point to an actual instance of a list, any type of list will do.

```
map.put(1, new LinkedList<Long>());
map.put(2, new ArrayList<Long>());
map.put(3, new Vector<Long>());
```

Answer (score 1):

`Map map = new Hashmap<Integer,List<Long>>;`

`map.put(1,new ArrayList<Long>());`